# from two arrays to one dataframe python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to put my values into two arrays and then to make them a dataframe. I am using python, numpy and pandas to do so.

my arrays are:

```
k = [7.0, 8.0, 6.55, 7.0000001, 10.12]
p = [6.94, 9.0, 4.44444, 13.0, 9.0876]
```

and I would like to put them into a pandas dataframe. When I print my dataframe, I would like to see this:

```
    a     b    c     d     e
k  7.0   8.0  6.6   7.0  10.1
p  6.9   9.0  4.4  13.0   9.1
```

How can I do that?

I read some related questions, but I can't get it right. One of the errors says that indexes must not be tuples, but, as you can see, I don't have tuples

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((k,p)),index=['k','p'])` ?

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always have as input to `pd.DataFrame` be a list of lists, which will generate the output you desire:

```
k = [7.0, 8.0, 6.55, 7.0000001, 10.12]
p = [6.94, 9.0, 4.44444, 13.0, 9.0876]

pd.DataFrame([k,p],columns=['a','b','c','d','f'],index=['k','p'])

    a   b   c   d   e
k   7.00    8.0 6.55000 7.0 10.1200
p   6.94    9.0 4.44444 13.0    9.0876
```

And if you want rounded:

```
pd.DataFrame([k,p],columns=['a','b','c','d','f'],index=['k','p']).round()

    a   b   c   d   e
k   7.0 8.0 7.0 7.0 10.0
p   7.0 9.0 4.0 13.0    9.0
```

for dynamic columns:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
pd.DataFrame([k,p],columns=list(ascii_lowercase[:len(k)]),index=['k','p']).round()
```

Comment: is it possible also to round the results?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([k,p],columns=['a','b','c','d','f'],index=['k','p']).round()` This could help.

Comment: you can import `ascii_lowercase` from the `string` module to make the column naming dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to other answers I got this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([k,p],columns=['a','b','c','d','f'],index=['k','p']).round(decimals=2)
```

How to get it step-by-step:

1) put arrays into another array by writing `array = [k,p]`. By printing it, result should look like this:

`[[7.0, 8.0, 6.55, 7.0000001, 10.12],[6.94, 9.0, 4.44444, 13.0, 9.0876]]`

2) write my column names into another array, arraycolnames. By printing it, result should look like this:
`['a','b','c','d','e']`

3) write my indexes names into another array, arrayindnames. By printing it, result should look like this:
`['k','p']`

4) create my dataframe by writing:

`df = pd.Dataframe(array, columns=arraycolnames, index=arrayindnames)`

5) round it using `.round()` method. By adding `decimals=2` I say I want decimals till the 2nd, but I can write any number of decimal places needed

`df.round(decimals=2)`

My final result, as I print df, is:

```
      a      b      c      d       e
k   7.00   8.00   6.55   7.00  10.12
p   6.94   9.00   4.44  13.00   9.09
```